# Why this class is GCed when static reference is present

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I am trying to understand how class loader leak is possible with static variables.
As I read in many places that Static variables are referenced by class objects which in turn are related with class loaders. Does this mean if I write a code like below then the Classloader will not be GCed? `private static final GCTester INSTANCE=new GCTester();`

```
public class GCTester {
 private static final GCTester INSTANCE=new GCTester();
  private GCTester() {
    System.out.println(this + " created");
  }
  @Override
  public void finalize() {
    System.out.println(this + " finalized");
  }
  }
```

And main class :

```
public class TestMe {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
System.out.println("in main");
testGetObject();
System.out.println("Second gc() call (in main)");
System.gc();
Thread.sleep(10000);
System.out.println("End of main");
 }

public static void testGetObject() throws Exception {
System.out.println("Creating ClassLoader");
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new File("./x").toURI().toURL()});
System.out.println("Loading Class");
Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("GCTester");

System.out.println("Getting static field");
Field field = clazz.getField("INSTANCE");

System.out.println("Reading static value");
Object object = field.get(null);
System.out.println("Got value: " + object);

System.out.println("First gc() call");
System.gc();
Thread.sleep(10000);
}
}
```

The output with class loading and unloading option enable:

```
   [0.108s][info][class,load] TestMe source: file:/C:/Users/someone/eclipse-workspace/Test/bin/
   [0.108s][info][class,load] java.lang.NamedPackage source: jrt:/java.base
   [0.108s][info][class,load] java.net.URLClassLoader source: jrt:/java.base
   in main
   Creating ClassLoader
  [0.109s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.access.JavaNetURLClassLoaderAccess source: jrt:/java.base
   [0.109s][info][class,load] java.net.URLClassLoader$7 source: jrt:/java.base
   [0.110s][info][class,load] java.net.URI$Parser source: jrt:/java.base
   Loading Class
   [0.111s][info][class,load] GCTester source: file:/C:/Users/someone/eclipse-workspace/Test/bin/
   Getting static field
   Reading static value
   [0.111s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory source: jrt:/java.base
   GCTester@782830e created
   Got value: GCTester@782830e
   First gc() call
   Second gc() call (in main)
   End of main
```

Here we can see that finalize is not called and same thing happens without static also `private final GCTester INSTANCE=new GCTester();`
So I do not understand why it says that

> Static variables are referenced by class objects which in turn are related with class loaders

How can I reproduce memory leak in meta space with static veriables?

Comment: When you remove the `static`, you create an instance field. Since you are never creating an instance, the initializer will never get executed (otherwise you had an infinite loop, creating an instance in the instance initializer). Without an instance, you will never see a finalization of an instance. Besides that, it’s not clear what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

> `System.gc();`

This is a hint, not a directive. There is no guarantee this is actually going to run any finalizers, so, unfortunately, it means that if you do *not* see the finalizer run, it means *nothing*. If you do see the finalizer, that is proof your object is being GCed.

A much better way to try to figure out if things are eligible for GC is to use debug tools based on JVMTI, such as visualvm.

Even if it did work, no, your classloader **cannot** be garbage collected here. Not because of 'static variables', but because of how you wrote your test method.

Some info is needed before I can explain why:

### Slots

Java code (`.java` files) are compiled down to bytecode (`.class` files), and in bytecode, local vars don't quite make it. These end up as so-called 'slots', but `javac` may overwrite a slot. For example, this method:

```
void foo() {
   int x = 5;
   System.out.println(x);
   int y = 10;
   System.out.println(y);
}
```

is likely going to end up compiled down to having 1 slots (or possibly even 0 slots, with both numbers inlined entirely). That's because this could have been written just as well as:

```
void foo() {
   int x = 5;
   System.out.println(x);
   x = 10;
   System.out.println(x);
}
```

The behaviour of `javac` is well specified (javac is not allowed to apply optimizations arbitrarily, it needs to follow a spec - there is a definitive 'that code uses 1 slot here' style answer to give, you can use `javap -c` to decompile this code and be sure if you are intrigued). Nevertheless, nobody* programs java with an acute sense of what their java code is going to precisely look like in bytecode, so trying to think about slots is not the way to go. Instead, realize that local variables, **even if out of scope**, may still be 'live' at the bytecode level. If you never touch them again in that method, also be aware they may not be.

Fortunately, **all** local variables and parameters completely disappear the moment the method ends. That's how you gain certainty: Once a method is done, you know for sure any objects it was referencing are no longer being prevented from GC because of that method.

### GC and threads

You've surely seen a stack trace, right? Every thread that is not 'dead' (a thread is dead once it has been both started, and then, finished / stopped. A dead thread will never be running code again) is currently running some method, but it got there because some other method called it, and some other method called that, all the way back up to the `run()` method - a stack trace lists them all. **every method** in that trace, of **every non-dead thread** is a GC starting point: Every local variable and parameter that these threads can access are NOT collectable, and then, every object you can 'reach' from this initial set of 'still active' objects is also considered 'still active' - keep going until you're done, and voila: You have your 'active objects' and your 'eligible for collection' objects. Lots and lots of methods have a `this` reference accessible, which is also a local variable/parameter, keep that in mind.

### Back to your problem

Your `Object o` local var is pointing at your singleton `GCTester` object, which is thus **a live object** and cannot be collected. (At that point your method is never going to touch that object again. This means that its slot may be reused, and thus, it would not be live. But it is not a good idea to attempt to do 'slot analysis', so you must assume the worst: If you don't want it to be GCed, it might be, and if you do want to, it won't be). When you have a live instance of class X, then class X cannot be collected. When a class cannot be collected, its classloader cannot be collected.

Thus, in order:

- The GC checks for live threads and finds yours.
- The GC finds live objects in the slots of every method in the stack of every thread. It finds, via your local var `o`, the instance of GCTester.
- That instance causes the GCTester.class to be non-eligible.
- That causes the loader to be non-eligible.

Actually *get rid of it* (best way: Put the interaction with GCTester in a separate helper method, but leave the gc() and sleep() calls where they are. Now you can be sure there is no method with a slot pointing at it).

Then, if your gc call isn't triggering the finalizer (because the spec says it does not have to), invest in learning visualvm or some other serious debugging tool.

*) I rounded down.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is slightly misleading. You seem to think that the `URLClassLoader` that you initialized here

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new File("./x").toURI().toURL()});
```

will be responsible for loading this class

```
Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("GCTester");
```

when in fact, the `URLClassLoader` will delegate loading the class to the application classloader, ie. the class loader that was used to initialize your `TestMe` class. See more details here

- [UrlClassLoader delegation and inheritance hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160415/urlclassloader-delegation-and-inheritance-hierarchy)

You can verify this by calling and printing out

```
clazz.getClassLoader()
```

It won't be the same object as `cl`.

This is mentioned in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.URL%5B%5D))

> The URLs will be searched in the order specified for classes and resources **after first searching in the parent class loader.**

You've probably ran your Java program with the `GCTester` class included in the classpath, so that's why the application class loader can find it and load it.

Instead, take it out, move it to another jar or provide it individually as a `.class` file somewhere that's not included in the classpath of your application. Then run your program again after adjusting the paths to be able to find it. For example

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new File("entirely-separate-dir/").toURI().toURL() });
Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("com.example.GCTester");
```

You can again verify that the `clazz`'s `ClassLoader` is actually the `URLClassLoader`, but your program should now print the `finalize` print statement.

```
com.example.GCTester@bebdb06 finalized
```

because the `GCTester` object referenced by the `GCTester.INSTANCE` field was garbage collected when the "owning" `ClassLoader` was also garbage collected.

You also ask

> How can I reproduce memory leak in meta space with static variables?

You'd have to keep holding on to a reference that directly or indirectly leads to the `ClassLoader` (the `URLClassLoader` in this example) that loaded the classes with those static variables.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, can you please give a code example to reproduce memory leak in meta space with static variables?

Comment: @Learner Like I said in the last paragraph, just keep a reference to something that has a reference to the `ClassLoader`. You can, for example, return `object` from your method, store it somewhere reachable, then ignore it, while you do other things in your program. You can think of that as a leak.